# Finding hashes with items from the array using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Sorry for missunderstanding for my fault I didn't check class of item...

I have an array:

```
array = [link1, link2, link3, link4, etc]
```

and array_of_hashes with two items: names and links

```
hash = [ :names, :links ] e.g.
array_of_hashes = [{ :names => name1, :links => link1}, {:names = name2, :links => link2}, ... ]
```

I want to do something with each pair of items from array_of_hashes which includes links from the array.

UPD: Revised data... sorry for missunderstanding.

Comment: {:name, :link} does not look like a valid hash to me. I think your question needs a lot more clarification. Please post your input and expected output more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the array of hashes and search the link array.

```
array = [:link1, :link2, :link3]
array_of_hashes = [{ :names => :name1, :links => :no_link}, {:names => :name2, :links => :link2}]

array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
  if array.any? {|s| s==hash[:links]}
    puts "Do something with #{hash[:names].to_s}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit vague of a question but here is a shot at it.

you will need to reorder what you're trying to access from the hash, unless :name is required.

```
arr = ["link0", "link1",..."linkN"]
hsh = { "link0", item0, "link1", item1, "link1", item2,..."linkN", itemN}
hsh.each_pair | link, item |
  do_something_foo(item) if arr.include?(link) # do_something_foo is a predefined function
end
```

> jagga99 wrote
>
> I want to do something with each item from hash which contain links from the array. Thanks a lot for your help.

If the [:name, :link] is the require pair, then you would need to identify which part is the item to do something with: the name or the link.

Comment: I want to proceed with name of each link which is included inside array of links